# wpfx:DateTimePicker how to set date and time manually

Tags: c#, wpf

I have

> wpfx:DateTimePicker x:Name="dat_reg"

and i want to set date and time now on window open how i can make it.
My code is this
 `<wpfx:DateTimePicker x:Name="dat_reg" Height="23" Margin="223,270,184,-237" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"></wpfx:DateTimePicker>`

```
  public frm_main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //dat_reg.SetValue(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

    }
```

But this does not work.Thank

Answer (score 1):

Instead of seting up value, use `SelectedDate` property from `DateTimePicker` . You can store Date and time in `DateTime` type, No need to convert it into `string` type

```
public frm_main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dat_reg.SelectedDate= DateTime.Now;
        //dat_reg.SelectedDate = new DateTime(2018, 05, 07); 
       //In this way you can assign instance of DateTime with specific Date and time

    }
```

Comment: it's not simply datepicker i'm using wpfx:DateTimePicker but thank anyway

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Value` property and the `FormatString` property:

```
dat_reg.Value = DateTime.Now;
dat_reg.Format = Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.DateTimeFormat.DateTimeFormat.Custom; 
dat_reg.FormatString = "d";
```